# How to read binary files?

Tags: python, file-io, binary, corruption, hex-editors

I'm trying to take a binary file and reverse the encryption on it using python.

The problem is that Python isn't reading what's actually in the file, and it seems like the internal data gets quite corrupt too.

Printing out the binary file from python yields:

```
b'[\xbb\x90\x92\x00\xdd\x7f\xe5\xe9\x81y\x82\x9a[\x0fOf\x19\t\xe8k\xa8R\xb5\x0c\x9f\xadZA\xb5\xd3\xef\xcd\xa9#U\xef\x996\xdc+N\xbe\xc8D\x1c?\xa8\xb3\xd7#\xbf\xb7\x18\xcd\xdf\xe5\xe5\xcf\xb5`?\xe3[J\x06\x041).'
```

While `HxD` yields:

```
5B BB 90 92 00 DD 7F E5 E9 81 79 82 9A 5B 0F 4F 66 19 09 E8 6B A8 52 B5 0C 9F AD 5A 41 B5 D3 EF CD A9 23 55 EF 99 36 DC 2B 4E BE C8 44 1C 3F A8 B3 D7 23 BF B7 18 CD DF E5 E5 CF B5 60 3F E3 5B 4A 06 04 31 29 2E
```

Python not only misses the first byte, but it starts to massively screw things up around the E9 byte.

How do I fix this?

edit: my code to read the file is as follows. The python debugger and the print function yield the error as above.

```
binary_file= open("Challenge-RE-Obfuscated", "rb")
full_string = binary_file.read()
```

Comment: what are you doing to get this far?  without any code it's difficult to suggest any ways to "fix this"…

Comment: Indeed, what @Sam said, so please [edit] your question and add the code you're using to read the file. FYI the usual way is simply by opening the file with `mode='rb'` where the `b` indicates binary mode.

Comment: Python does not miss the first byte; you do (it's the `[` in Python's bstring). There also is nothing wrong with the rest of its string representation, as far as I can see. The `y` gets truthfully represented as `79` in the hex dump, for example.

Comment: @zaph I didn't intend to say that the python implementation was wrong, my thought process was that there was something wrong with my installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bytes` representation, printable characters are displayed literally, so 0x5b is displayed as `[`, 0x79 is `y` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think Python might be doing what you're telling it.  at least those look the same to my interpreter!

```
inp = '5B BB 90 92 00 DD 7F E5 E9 81 79 82 9A 5B 0F 4F 66 19 09 E8 6B A8 52 B5 0C 9F AD 5A 41 B5 D3 EF CD A9 23 55 EF 99 36 DC 2B 4E BE C8 44 1C 3F A8 B3 D7 23 BF B7 18 CD DF E5 E5 CF B5 60 3F E3 5B 4A 06 04 31 29 2E'

bb = bytes(int(b, base=16) for b in inp.split())
```

gives `bb`

```
b'[\xbb\x90\x92\x00\xdd\x7f\xe5\xe9\x81y\x82\x9a[\x0fOf\x19\t\xe8k\xa8R\xb5\x0c\x9f\xadZA\xb5\xd3\xef\xcd\xa9#U\xef\x996\xdc+N\xbe\xc8D\x1c?\xa8\xb3\xd7#\xbf\xb7\x18\xcd\xdf\xe5\xe5\xcf\xb5`?\xe3[J\x06\x041).'
```

and:

```
' '.join('{:02x}'.format(b) for b in bb)
```

gives:

```
'5b bb 90 92 00 dd 7f e5 e9 81 79 82 9a 5b 0f 4f 66 19 09 e8 6b a8 52 b5 0c 9f ad 5a 41 b5 d3 ef cd a9 23 55 ef 99 36 dc 2b 4e be c8 44 1c 3f a8 b3 d7 23 bf b7 18 cd df e5 e5 cf b5 60 3f e3 5b 4a 06 04 31 29 2e'
```

running `[i for i in bb[:10]]` or `list(bb[:10])` gives:

```
[91, 187, 144, 146, 0, 221, 127, 229, 233, 129]
```

which might be closer to the output you're expecting?